# How to best do server-side geo clustering?

Tags: solr, cluster-analysis, server-side, geo, localsolr

I want to do pre-clustering for a set of approx. 500,000 points.

I haven't started yet but this is what I had thought I would do:

- store all points in a localSOLR index
- determine "natural cluster positions" according to some administrative information (big cities for example)
- and then calculate a cluster for each city:

  - for each city

    - for each zoom level

      - query the index to get the points contained in a radius around the city (the length of the radius depends on the zoom level)

This should be quite efficient because there are only 100 major cities and SOLR queries are very fast. But a little more thinking revealed it was wrong:

1. there may be clusters of points that are more "near" one another than near a city: they should get their own cluster
2. at some zoom levels, some points will not be within the acceptable distance of any city, and so they will not be counted
3. some cities are near one another and therefore, some points will be counted twice (added to both clusters)

There are other approaches:

- examine each point and determine to which cluster it belongs; this eliminates problems 2 and 3 above, but not 1, and is also extremely inefficient
- make a (rectangular) grid (for each zoom level); this works but will result in crazy / arbitrary clusters that don't "mean" anything

I guess I'm looking for a general purpose geo-clustering algorithm (or *idea*) and can't seem to find any.

---

Edit to answer comment from Geert-Jan

I'd like to build "natural" clusters, yes, and yes I'm afraid that if I use an arbitrary grid, it will not reflect the reality of the data. For example if there are many events that occur around a point that is at or near the intersection of two rectangles, I should get just one cluster but will in fact build two (one in each rectangle).

Originally I wanted to use localSOLR for performance reasons (and because I know it, and have better experience indexing a lot of data into SOLR than loading it in a conventional database); but since we're talking of pre-clustering, maybe performance is not that important (although it should not take days to visualize a result of a new clustering experiment). My first approach of querying lots of points according to a predefined set of "big points" is clearly flawed anyway, the first reason I mentioned being the strongest: clusters should reflect the reality of the data, and not some other bureaucratic definition (they will clearly overlap, sure, but data should come first).

There is a great clusterer for live clustering, that has been added to the core Google Maps API: [Marker Clusterer](http://gmaps-utility-library.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/1.0/docs/reference.html). I wonder if anyone has tried to run it "offline": run it for any amount of time it needs, and then store the results?

Or is there a clusterer that examines each point, point after point, and outputs clusters with their coordinates and number of points included, and which does this in a reasonable amount of time?

Comment: Do I understand correctly that with all approaches you fear you could get false positives and/or false negatives because you start out with some sort of non-natural partitioning of the searchspace,  (presumably for performance reasons). 

could you elaborate a bit on what these points are? You said: 'make a (rectangular) grid (for each zoom level); this works but will result in crazy / arbitrary clusters that don't "mean" anything'. What would clusters of points ideally be meaning to you? 

Perhaps you don't need the non-natural partitions, but without some more insight I can't really say.

Comment: Sorry I didn't see your comment earlier, I was relying on automatic notification and apparently that doesn't include comments... I'm updating my question to answer your comment.

Comment: Without much time at the moment: have a look at algorithm-classes: Hierarchical based clustering (which could get lumping/splitting of smaller clusters into bigger clusters based on zoom-level. Also look at the concept of "density based clustering" in contrast to "distance based clustering". I feel "density based clustering" might probably give more natural looking clusters for your goal. These algo's are not specifically geo-related (but of course are spatial). This may not need to be a problem, bc on relatively small areas (like cities) you can probably forget the earth is 'round'.. hth

Comment: Have you figured out anything here?  We're trying to do the same...

Comment: Can you provide an update on what you ended up doing?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look into advanced clustering algorithms such as OPTICS.

With a good database index, it should be fairly fast.